# How to disable the trailing comma after the decorator in vscode when using prettier

Tags: typescript, configuration, visual-studio-code

My code looks like this

```
import { ApiController, Controller } from "./lib/rest";

[Controller("test")];
export class TestController extends ApiController {}
```

Here vscode inserts the trailing comma after the decorator

> [Controller("test")];

I couldn't figure out how to disable this behaviour only for decorators.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a workaround to solve your problem. Instead of prettier you can use the extension called "beautify" to solve the comma trailing issue.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

if you want to stick on to prettier then in vscode

file > preferences > settings > on the user settings >

`"prettier.trailingComma": "none"`  or change it to `"prettier.trailingComma": "es5"`

Hope it will fix your problem.